# Генерация swagger через консоль

Tags: php, swagger

Делаю документацию на swagger мой код использую библиотеку Swagger-PHP

```
    /**
 * @OA\Info(
 *     version="1.0",
 *     title="Parser images links"
 * )
 */
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/images",
 *     summary="Get links images",
 *         @OA\MediaType(
 *             mediaType="application/json",
 *             @OA\Schema(
 *                 @OA\Property(
 *                     property="url",
 *                     type="string"
 *                 ),
 *                 example={"url": "http://okozorko.ru"}
 *             )
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="Successful operation"
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response=404,
 *         description="Not found"
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response= 400,
 *         description="Bad Request"
 *     ),
 * )
 */
```

как сделать, чтобы файл swagger.yml формировался через консоль?
То есть , я ввожу команду путь и у меня выводится swagger.yml

Comment: В документации всё указано, что именно вам не понятно из примера в https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php?

Comment: да, именно. ввожу ./vendor/bin/openapi --output api/openapi.yaml но он пишет Error: Specify at least one path.

Comment: Разобрался  ./vendor/bin/openapi api -o api

Answer (score 1):

```
./vendor/bin/openapi api -o api
```